# Двойной щелчок по сворачиваемому блоку портит разметку

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено

На странице [справки по редактору](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) двойной щелчок по сворачиваемому блоку, содержащему блоки для свёрнутого и развёрнутого состояния, скрывает оба. При этом восстановить блок, который должен показываться свёрнутом состоянии, невозможно без обновления страницы.

[Скринвидео](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/26RmmR1kJNUX/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0.wmv) (2 МБ)

---

1. Before (uncollapsed)

[image]

2. Click on heading to collapse

[image]

3. Now double-click on heading

[image]

Comment: Спасибо! Очень интересный дефект! Попробую выяснить, что к чему.

Comment: что интересно, не на всех пунктах: `Горизонтальные линии`, `Расширенное цитирование: Вложение`, `Подсветка синтаксиса в коде`

Comment: thanks, the addition of the images has helped me understand the issue